# OSX - signed installer rejected

Tags: macos, productsign

I'm using following to sign my installer :

```
productsign --sign "Developer ID Installer: ACME, Inc (ABCDE12345)" "my-package-unsigned.pkg" "my-package-signed.pkg"
```

Output is following:

```
productsign: using timestamp authority for signature 
productsign: signing product with identity "Developer ID Installer: ACME, Inc (ABCDE12345)" from keychain /Users/johnd/Library/Keychains/login.keychain 
productsign: Wrote signed product archive to my-package-signed.pkg
```

Later, I check my installer and obtain following :

```
spctl -a -vvvv --type install my-package-signed.pkg

my-package-signed.pkg: rejected
origin=Developer ID Installer: ACME, Inc (ABCDE12345)
```

Any clue ?

Comment: You should use `pkgutil --check-signature my-package-signed.pkg` for PKGs, rather than `spctl` to verify the signing is correct. `spctl` asserts the security/gatekeeper policy more than the code-signing, and is subject to local computer settings.

Answer (score 0):

Waited a few days and installer reported 'accepted' status again. Not sure what fixed it. Maybe a computer restart or an Apple update.